# How to add multiple numbers using a method in java?

Tags: java, php

I have a PHP function for adding multiple numbers,

```
function add(...$numbers) {  
  $sum = 0;
  $ad = array();
  foreach ($numbers as $n) {  
      $sum += $n;
      $ad[] = $n;
  }
  $ret = "Sum of ".implode(" , ", $ad)." is ".$sum;
  return $ret;
}
```

what I want is how to convert this PHP function into java method,
THANK YOU VERY MUCH to those who will answer my question.

Comment: You will have to use argument array. `*args` mostly.

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? Show your code. Where are you stuck?

Comment: try using varargs in java.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow isn't a free code-conversion service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because translating programs is off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass value to be sum as an array or var args.

```
public int add(int... nums) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int num : nums) {
            sum = sum + num;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is with variable number of arguments. Java does support it, see this example:

```
package com.javapapers.corejava;

public class VarArgSample {

  static int sum(int i, int... marks) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int mark : marks) {
      total = total + mark;
    }
    return total;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //invoking with variable arguments
    System.out.println(sum(1, 2, 3));

    //same invocation using an array
    int arr[] = {2,3};
    System.out.println(sum(1, arr));
  }
}
```

This examples comes from: http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-variable-arguments/

Comment: What's the point of `i`?